# How to work around 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FirebaseUser' error

Tags: firebase, flutter, future

I have a FirebaseActions class which is doing signup and signin works for me. I added a getCurrentUser method in it. I'm calling that function from my HomeScreen widget. I need to put the returned value(type= FirebaseUser) into a variable in my HomeScreen to reach loggedInUser.email. But I get this error. My question; is there any way to get a FirebaseUser type data into a Future type variable? When I write this function in HomeScreen instead of FirebasAction class, it works but is it the best practice?

**FirebaseActions class**

```
static getCurrentUser(context) async {
    final user = await _auth.currentUser().catchError((error) {
      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(AppSnackBar.appSnackBar(error.message));
    });

    if (user != null) {
      return user;
    }
  }
```

**HomeScreen widget**

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

  FirebaseUser loggedInUser;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loggedInUser = FirebaseActions.getCurrentUser(context);
    print(loggedInUser.toString());
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because you didn't specify a return type in your `getCurrentUser()` function.

Replace your code with the one below and everything will work fine.

To solve this issue:
Check the code below: It works perfectly fine:

**Firebase Action Class**

```
// give your function a return type
static Future<FirebaseUser> getCurrentUser(context) async {
    final user = await _auth.currentUser().catchError((error) {
      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(AppSnackBar.appSnackBar(error.message));
    });

    if (user != null) {
      return user;
    }
  }
```

**Home Screen Widget**

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

  FirebaseUser loggedInUser;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    call the function here
    logInUser();
    print(loggedInUser.toString());
  }
```

I hope this helps

**UPDATE**

```
// create a new function to log in user
void logInUser() async {
 // await the result because you are invoking a future method
    loggedInUser = await FirebaseActions.getCurrentUser(context);
}
```

Comment: The problem is; when I try to get loggedInUser with await, it says "await can only be used in an async function". But  I cant do that, because initState can not be async.What should I do?

Comment: create a function name logInUser and call it in initState. Check my code. I updated it.

Comment: yep, I was doing that when you writing this answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad it helped you !

Answer (score 2):

You are not specified return type of method and also method is async, so you have to put await where you are calling.

```
 static Future<FirebaseUser> getCurrentUser(context) async {
```

also, add await where you are calling.

```
loggedInUser = await FirebaseActions.getCurrentUser(context);
```

update:

create new function and call in that function.

```
callme() async{  
 loggedInUser = FirebaseActions.getCurrentUser(context);
    print(loggedInUser.toString());
}
```

initstate:

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    callme();
  }
```

Comment: The problem is; when I try to get loggedInUser with await, it says "await can only be used in an async function". But  I cant do that, because initState can not be async.What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I handle async functions in my initstate:

```
FirebaseActions.getCurrentUser(context).then((val){loggedInUser = val});
```

Also make sure you specify the return type in your asynchronous function.

```
Future<FirebaseUser> getCurrentUser(context) async {...
```

Comment: it is another good option to solve this with callback function. Thank you.